# Python: How to save additional inputs to my data list?

Tags: python

How do I save new inputs to my **data** list?

Currently, when I enter text into the input box it displays in my list: **data**. However, when I clear the input box and add a new value, this value is added to the data list while the previously entered value seems to disappear. I want each value added to remain in the list. Im new to python and coding in general. All help is greatly appreciated! (Code displayed below)

```
import Tkinter as tk

class Example(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        # create a prompt, an input box, an output label,
        # and a button to do the saving
        self.prompt = tk.Label(self, text="Enter your Filepath:", anchor="w")
        self.entry = tk.Entry(self)
        self.submit = tk.Button(self, text="Save", command = self.save)
        self.output = tk.Label(self, text="")
        self.clear_button = tk.Button(self, text="Clear text", command=self.clear_text)

        # lay the widgets out on the screen. 
        self.prompt.pack(side="top", fill="x")
        self.entry.pack(side="top", fill="x", padx=20)
        self.output.pack(side="top", fill="x", expand=True)
        self.submit.pack(side="bottom")
        self.clear_button.pack(side="bottom")


    def clear_text(self):
        self.entry.delete(0, 'end')

    def save(self):
        # get the value from the input widget, save
        # it to list data
        data = []

        try:
            a = self.entry.get()
            result = data.append(a)

        except ValueError:
            result = "Please enter filepaths only"

        # set the output widget to have our result
        self.output.configure(text=result)
        print (data)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    Example(root).pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `data` is a local variable and it is being reassigned to an empty list every time you press the submit button. So there are two reasons why your values are "disappearing". 1: `data` is a local variable so when you exit your `save` function it is wiped. 2: When you call `save` you manually overwrite it with `data = []`

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! I moved data outside of save function but the program still doesnt create the list. How should I solve this issue?

Comment: Update the question with your revised code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution...

```
import Tkinter as tk
data = []
class Example(tk.Frame):


def __init__(self, parent):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

    # create a prompt, an input box, an output label,
    # and a button to do the computation
    self.prompt = tk.Label(self, text="Enter your Filepath:", anchor="w")
    self.entry = tk.Entry(self)
    self.submit = tk.Button(self, text="Save", command = self.save)
    self.output = tk.Label(self, text="")
    self.clear_button = tk.Button(self, text="Clear text", command=self.clear_text)

    # lay the widgets out on the screen. 
    self.prompt.pack(side="top", fill="x")
    self.entry.pack(side="top", fill="x", padx=20)
    self.output.pack(side="top", fill="x", expand=True)
    self.submit.pack(side="bottom")
    self.clear_button.pack(side="bottom")


def clear_text(self):
    self.entry.delete(0, 'end')


def save(self):
    # get the value from the input widget, convert
    # it to an int, and do a calculation

    try:
        a = self.entry.get()
        result = data.append(self.entry.get())

    except ValueError:
        result = "Please enter filepaths only"


    # set the output widget to have our result
    self.output.configure(text=result)
    print (data)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    Example(root).pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```